# How to call an outside function within a WP loop and get the "next" item, but for specific slugs

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress child theme workspace, I am trying to learn how to optimize my code below to be more efficient in its PHP process.  I have 10 images total that I'm working with. **I want any number of these images to be called onto different pages by slug.**  I know in PHP how to return once from a function, but how do I say in PHP...

- "I want photos 1, 2, 6 to go to slugA"
- "I want photos 2, 3, 5, 9 to go to slugB"
- "I want photos 1, 7 to go to slugC"
- etc...

This is what I have so far

```php
//DEFINING ALL MY PHOTOS AND RETURNING THEM

function my_post_photos (
  $mQuery = 1,
  $image01 = "filler_01.jpg",
  $image02 = "filler_02.jpg",
  $image03 = "filler_03.jpg",
  $image04 = "filler_04.jpg",
  $image05 = "filler_05.jpg",
  $image06 = "filler_06.jpg",
  $image07 = "filler_07.jpg",
  $image08 = "filler_08.jpg",
  $image09 = "filler_09.jpg",
  $image10 = "filler_10.jpg"
  ): string
{
  $vars = get_defined_vars();
  foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    $placeholders[] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/images/' . $value;
  }

  return $placeholders[$mQuery];
}


//FURTHER DOWN THIS SAME PAGE...WITHIN MY WP LOOP, CALLING THEM

<?php 
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
   //WITH THE BELOW $i, I AM FULLY AWARE THAT THE NUMBER OF PHOTOS LOADS IS DEPENDENT ON HOW MANY TIMES MY LOOP CYCLES.  I'M COOL WITH THAT BECAUSE I'M EVENTUALLY GOING TO HAVE MORE PHOTOS THAN POSTS.
   $i=1;
     while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
       $current_page = sanitize_post($GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object());
       $slug = $current_page->post_name;
  ?>
  
  <?php
    if ($slug == "slugA") {
    ?>
      <div>
        <h6>
          <!-- //THIS FUNCTION LOADS EACH PHOTO PERFECTLY FINE, BUT HOW CAN I ONLY RETURN PHOTOS 1, 2, 6 HERE? -->
          <img src="<?php echo my_career_placeholder($i); ?>" border="0" alt="">
        </h6>
       </div>
       <?php
       } elseif ($slug = "slugB") {
         //HOW CAN I RETURN ONLY PHOTOS 2, 3, 5, 9 HERE?
       } elseif ($slug = "slugC") {
         //HOW CAN I RETURN ONLY PHOTOS 1, 7 HERE?
       }
       ?>
      <?php 
        $i++;
        endif;
        endwhile; 
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Comment: Your main function signature is very strange, unless you actually intend to allow callers to change the image filenames when calling. I think this looks more correct/normal to me: https://3v4l.org/HICKU

Comment: I just made an update to it. thanks!

Comment: Not fully-related to your question, but unless you have a specific need I usually steer people towards [`get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/12496) over dedicated WP_Query's. Your code is in no way wrong, however.

Comment: in your opinion what would be the upper hand or advantage if I made that switch?

Comment: The executive summary is that it "returns an array of posts, doesn't modify global variables and is safe to use anywhere", however to learn more I would just encourage you to read over the post I linked to, it has a lot more information and nuance. However, like I said, your code isn't wrong, it is just something I steer people towards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code as a whole, I think your main function could be rewritten as follows:

```php
function my_post_photos(...$indexes): array
{
    $pathPrefix = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/dist/images/';

    $placeholders = [
        $pathPrefix.'filler_01.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_02.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_03.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_04.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_05.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_06.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_07.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_08.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_09.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_10.jpg',
    ];

    $ret = [];
    foreach ($indexes as $index) {
        if (isset($placeholders[$index])) {
            $ret[] = $placeholders[$index];
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

This would allow you to call it and pass as many indexes in as you want by doing `my_post_photos(3,5)`, which would return an array that you could loop over.

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/8aq6d

Additional optimizations could be done if you truly name your images in that consistent manner, but I'm just keeping this simple for now.

**edit**

Based on your comments, I think you want to call the function in the loop and get the "next" item, but for the specific slug.

If that's right, one way to do this would be to create a second array that maps slugs to image indexes. You can then use `static` with that array which means that subsequent calls to the function won't recreate the array, but instead use the first one. Lastly, you can use `array_shift` which gets you the first item from an array and actually removes that index from the array. (The function `array_shift` is considered non-performant for large arrays, if I understand things correctly, but I don't think you'll notice that here at all.)

The code below changes this back to returning a string (or null), and can be called repeatadly with a known-slug to get the "next" item. If you'd ever have more posts than images you could take the "next" and append it to the end of the array giving you a circular pool, too.

```php
function my_post_photos(string $slug): ?string
{
    $pathPrefix = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/dist/images/';

    $placeholders = [
        $pathPrefix.'filler_01.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_02.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_03.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_04.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_05.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_06.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_07.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_08.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_09.jpg',
        $pathPrefix.'filler_10.jpg',
    ];
    
    // Mapping of slugs to placeholders
    // NOTE: This array is created static so that it only ever
    // gets created once in the lifetime of the PHP request
    static $slugToPlaceholders = [
        'slugA' => [1, 2, 6],
        'slugB' => [2, 3, 5, 9],
        'slugC' => [1, 7],
    ];
    
    // Unknown slug, return null
    if(!isset($slugToPlaceholders[$slug])){
        return null;
    }
    
    // Grab the next unused index, and remove it from the array
    $nextIndex = array_shift($slugToPlaceholders[$slug]);
    
    // Return either the image or nothing if we're out of indexes
    return $placeholders[$nextIndex] ?? null;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/JDKOH

Comment: It feels like its almost there.  Just getting a little PHP Notice that says " Notice: Array to string conversion..." in at the line when I run ` <img src="<?php echo my_post_photos(1,3,5); ?>" border="0" alt="">`

Comment: Yes. This code will always return an array now, so you'd need to [loop over](https://3v4l.org/9fdUV) that array always. If I misunderstood your "HOW CAN I RETURN ONLY PHOTOS 2, 3, 5, 9 HERE?" then I would change the function.

Comment: this has been a tremendous help. I'm learning a lot.  there is just one issue I'm trying to solve with this approach.  If we run the foreach function "inside the wp loop" lke so : `  foreach (my_post_photos(1,2) as $imagePath) {`, the loop is calling index 1, every time it loops.  it should only call index 1 once, then on the next iteration, call 2.  It feels like we need $i to check if its value is found in any of the ...$indexes.  if it is, then process the function....just a thought.  I'm trying stuff out.

Comment: @klewis, I edited my answer with what I think you are looking to achieve

Comment: Absolutely amazing.  Your last solution Is pure gold for my current task.  Thank you for helping me learn some great things with PHP!